# Check request origin and validate email sender - Node.js

Tags: node.js, validation, email, mailgun

I am building a platform that has a messaging system.

I would like to post messages from emails, and for that I created a route on Mailgun that redirects the emails to my API.

This part is working, but I need to validate the request before actually posting the message to my platform. I will see the sender's email to look on my database for the author of the message and the target of the email to select the group of profiles that will receive the message.

So, an example: 
if I receive an email

```
from: user@domain.com
to: group@myplatform.com 
message: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...
```

I would check for "user@domain.com" on my database and see if he can post to "group" and if so I would post the message to it.

The problem is, I need to validate two things:

- If the request on my API really came from Mailgun, to avoid spoofing
- Check if the sender of the e-mail is authentic, not any spam

To do the first I saw that I could use ***req.connection.remoteAddress*** on Node to get the origin, and then I tried to do a reverse lookup on the IP and see if it was from Mailgun, but the reverse lookup found nothing.

To validate the email origin I saw that I could use the ***Received*** headers on the email, and then I thought about checking them with a DNS lookup and see if the MX record matched.

I am really new to this, and my question is, is there an easier way to validate this two steps and is it safe at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an "Inbound Spam Filter" checkbox that you can enable when setting up your domain in the Mailgun Dashboard.

See the "Securing Webhooks" section of the Mailgun docs to avoid spoofing.

https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#webhooks

> To verify the webhook is originating from Mailgun you need to:
>
> - Concatenate timestamp and token values.
> - Encode the resulting string with the HMAC algorithm (using your API Key as a key and SHA256 digest mode).
> - Compare the resulting hexdigest to the signature.
> - Optionally, you can cache the token value locally and not honor any subsequent request with the same token. This will prevent replay attacks.
> - Optionally, you can check if the timestamp is not too far from the current time.